# How can I pass the value of my selected item into the value of input field

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have fetched data items in my search component, but I would like to be able to click on searched item and the value would automatically be printed in my input field. For now I am only able to search and get the results, but nothing is happening when I am clicking on the specific searched item.

**Example:**

I am searching for country -> I'll write into my input "Cam" -> now my filtered data are coming up and giving me my suggestions -> Cambodia, Cameroon -> I click on Cambodia and in input field I can see value of Cambodia

As I said, my filtering works fine, I just need to be able to pass the value from clicked item to input field

```js
const [search, setSearch ] = useState(undefined);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
 }
```

```js
<input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={search} />
{filteredData &&
  filteredData.map((data, index) => (
    <li key={`index${index}`}>
      <div className="col-6 text pt-2">
        <h5>{data.name}</h5>
    </li>
  ))}
```

I am already passing in input value={search}, but I probably also have to set up something in my list of items - <li tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the state in the `onClick` handler of `li`:

```
 <li key={`index${index}`} onClick={()=>{setSearch({data.name})}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed an `onClick` event handler from list `li` item.

```
  <input type="search" value={searchItem} onChange={handleChange} />
  <ul>
    {listData.map((x,i) => (
      <li key={i} onClick={handleClick}>{x}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>

  Searched Result = > {clickedText}
</div>
```

Running Example - https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-react-65754485-oih9d?file=/src/Search.js:666-918